# Network problem in Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, netplan

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 live server edition ,while installing I configured two ethernet and everything worked fine,after the first reboot I cannot ping any address or connect to any network ,I tried netplan generate and apply , apply didn't work. Anyone know how to fix this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2):

Netplan is very strict about spacing, indentation, etc. For example, this is acceptable:

```
ethernets:
  enp3s0:
```

But this is not:

```
ethernets:
      enp3s0:
```

You may gain some insights by consulting the example files; for instance:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan.io/examples/static.yaml
```

I suggest that you amend your yaml file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.1.64/24
      gateway4: 10.10.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: note that in the original file you have 'nameservers: [...] search: - 8.8.4.4' which is certainly incorrect.  search: is for domain names, not for DNS servers.